# I am getting error for changing file path using selenium chrome driver in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I am trying to change the file path of chrome webDriver in java whiile saving a file, but i am getting the error in my code at "options.setExperimentalOption" (line 6 in code), how can solve this ?

As i am new to selenium any type of suggestions willbe helpful .

```
String downloadFilepath = "C:\\seleniumDownloads";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Please help in solving this or is there any other methods for changing the filepath ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Could you confirm if you have imported `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions` class. Also, it would be great if you provide complete stacktrace of the error to help us better understand the situation.

Comment: @ApurvChatterjee Yes,I have imported 'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions' even though i am getting error at 'options.setExperimentalOption' .

Comment: @Guy I am getting error as                                                              
 'cannot find symbol
 symbol:methodsetExperimentalOption(String,HashMap<String,Object>)
 location: variable options of type ChromeOptions'                                 at line 6 in my code i.e..,'options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs)'

Comment: where you are mentioning your webdriver path. You are just changing the default download path

Comment: @santhoshkumar i have already mentioned the webdriver path at the beginning my error is not with webdriver, i want to change the file download path.

Comment: Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\New_Download");
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/santhoshkumar/Softwares/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe");"
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps); //This works in  my local

Comment: @santhoshkumar I copied your code in my local but still i am facing same error at options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs).

Comment: What Selenium version are you using?

Comment: I am using chromedriver 2.29 and chrome V59 with selenium 3.4 @vinay can you confirm this

Comment: @Guy for googlechrome webdriver i am using latest version available in 'http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/' website i.e.., version 2.30. and for Selenium 3.4 version

Comment: @santhoshkumar  I have added the screenshot for the better understing of my problem.. please look into this for helping to findout where i am doing mistake.

Comment: @Guy I have added the screenshot for the better understing of my problem.. please look into this for helping to findout where i am doing mistake

Comment: @ApurvChatterjee I have added the screenshot for the better understing of my problem.. please look into this for helping to findout where i am doing mistake

Comment: Can you mouseh over to the setexperimentaloption and show the screenshot

Comment: Did you try `Alt + Enter` to show the hints? Also, try casting `chromePrefs` to `Object`.

Comment: @santhoshkumar the popup in the image is after mouse hover .

Comment: @Guy yeah i have tried but it didin't worked, is there any other way to change filepath otherthan this ?

Comment: @vinay No that I know of. It shouldn't make difference but try changing `chromePrefs` from `Map` to `HashMap`.

Comment: @Guy Can i know the JarList names that you have used in your code ?

Comment: @santhoshkumar Can i know the JarList names that you have used in your code ?

Comment: import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

Comment: @santhoshkumar not the imports santhosh the jar libraries which you have downloaded and imported to the project. I want those names . It seems my error is because of those imports. I have imported 'selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar','selenium-chrome-driver-2.26.0.jar','org.json.jar'. These are the jars i have downloaded and imported to my project can you tell yours ? Thanks

Comment: I have imported only selenium server standalone 3.4.0 jar.., No separate jar for chromedriver since we are referencing it with setproperty.(2.29). No other jars.

Comment: Make sure your chrome browser is also updated. Its Version 59.0.3071.115

Comment: @vinay I'm not using Java. However its not a problem with your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While you work with `Selenium` 3.4.0, `chromedriver` v2.30 and `Chrome` 59.0 through Selenium-java bindings the following code block works fine:

> Ensure that while you use **`Map<String, Object>`** and **`HashMap<String, Object>()`** add **`import java.util.Map;`** and **`import java.util.HashMap;`** respectively.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Q45004905_DownloadPath 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        String downloadFilepath = "C:\\seleniumDownloads";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
        driver.get("https://google.com");

    }

}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: before i run the program itself it is showing the error at 'options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs)' , Is their any other way to change the filepath ?

Comment: I have added the screenshot for the better understing of my problem.. please look into this for helping to findout where i am doing mistake

Comment: I need to see the line `Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();` clear in your code block. Apart from that can you consider upgrading your Java to Version 8 Update 131? Thanks

Comment: my line is 'Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>()' and can i know the jars list name your are using ?

Comment: Did you upgrade Java to Version 8 Update 131 and added back the jars in your project? Thanks